# How to install python-guestfs and libguestfs-tools in python virtual environment?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, python-2.7, virtualenv

Can any one help me out to install `python-guestfs` and `libguestfs-tools` in python virtual environment?

I tried to install those packages with the help of pip install but it fails to install because it throws an error `package not found`.

Comment: Please show the _exact_ command and the _exact_ error produced.

Comment: Bcoz You dont have the package inside the pip  ,you can install through apt-get install python-guestfs

Comment: I've filed an RFE here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1075594 "RFE: python-libguestfs should be available on pypi"

Answer (score 3):

Try these commands,

```
sudo apt-get install python-guestfs
sudo apt-get install libguestfs-tools
```

OR

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install python-guestfs
sudo pip install libguestfs-tools
```

Comment: I tried through pip install, the error was "No distributions at all found for python-guestfs". If we install through apt-get it will install and sit in the system but not in the virtual-env

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416938/pip-can-not-install-anything

Comment: you cant install it through pip because these packages are not there at `pypi` as pip installs packages maintained by pypi

Answer (score 1):

I have started work on this.  See the commit here which will allow you to build a python distribution of guestfs:

https://github.com/libguestfs/libguestfs/commit/fcbfc4775fa2a44020974073594a745ca420d614

Unfortunately we are waiting on the Python Software Foundation to resolve a licensing problem with the PyPi website before I am able to upload anything.

Comment: What is the licensing problem?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to pip install it from their self hosted folder that is [provided here](http://libguestfs.org/download/python).

You will end up running the command:

```
pip install http://libguestfs.org/download/python/guestfs-1.XX.YY.tar.gz
```

This will trigger Python to pull down raw source and build it. Make sure that you have `libguestfs` library for C installed on your system as well as `python3-devel` package for this to work.

NOTE: instructions are listed on http://libguestfs.org/guestfs-python.3.html

Comment: It would improve your answer if you would include the instructions in it.